# Shopping cart price rule percent discount

Tags: magento-1, shopping-cart-price-rules

I would like to give a family & friends 40% discount with a max. subtotal of €250

```
Actions:
Apply: percent of product price discount
Discount: 40
Apply the rule: if all of these conditions are true
Price in Shopping cart is equal or smaller than €250
```

(Also tried it without € ) but it still is giving after €250 the 40% discount.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You want to add 40% discount for cart below €250 (so max discount for this is €100)  or make max discount for €250? Max €250 should be before or after discount

Comment: the discount should be €100 max

Comment: What version of Magento are you using ?

Comment: Magento 1.9.2.4

Comment: Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

what you are trying is correct : **if all of these conditions are true: Price in Shopping cart is equal or smaller than €250** , if that dont work for you, you can try another option as in below image. also please check that Is any Other Rule is having higher Priority may , it may conflict with this one....

[image]